# Datatables language error

Tags: jquery, json, datatables-1.10

I'm trying to use a language json file in Datatables but I always get a strange error in console.
If I write

```
table = $('#myTable').DataTable({
    "language": { "url": "//cdn.datatables.net/plug-ins/1.10.16/i18n/English.json" },
    "searching": false,
    ...
    ...
```

I get this error in datatables.min.js (line 55): TypeError: f[0] is undefined (and my page hangs!)

If, instead, I use all the language declarations such as:

```
"language": {
    "sEmptyTable": "No data available in table",
    "sInfo":       "Showing _START_ to _END_ of _TOTAL_ entries",
    "sInfoEmpty":  "Showing 0 to 0 of 0 entries",
    ...
    ...
```

all runs fine...

Using a non minified version of datatables i saw that the error is here:

```
function _fnScrollDraw ( settings )
{
    // Given that this is such a monster function, a lot of variables are use
    // to try and keep the minimised size as small as possible
    var
        scroll         = settings.oScroll,
        scrollX        = scroll.sX,
        scrollXInner   = scroll.sXInner,
        scrollY        = scroll.sY,
        barWidth       = scroll.iBarWidth,
        divHeader      = $(settings.nScrollHead),

        // !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
        divHeaderStyle = divHeader[0].style, // !!!! divHeader[0] is undefined
        // !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
        divHeaderInner = divHeader.children('div'),
        divHeaderInnerStyle = divHeaderInner[0].style,
```

So there's an error somewhere if you use scrolling features and an external language file... some ideas?

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $('#example').DataTable({
             "language": {
                "url": "//cdn.datatables.net/plug-ins/9dcbecd42ad/i18n/Turkish.json"
            }
        });
    } );
```

You can add language files from data table ready libraries with this plugin.

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.